# Dropdown menu won't close using - Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Even after clicking an item on the dropdown menu, it doesn't close, it stays open. Very weird.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

# enable browser logging
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities = d, options=chrome_options)
driver.fullscreen_window()

driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/manuel")

maerke = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_carSelectedMake"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-results-1"]/li[75]').click()
```

I tried adding:

```
driver.switch_to.active_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

which I found in another SO thread, but it didn't work.

Also tried adding send_keys() after the last click(), still not working.

Update: - Still no solution.

Comment: maybe scrolling to the element and then clicking the element helps.

Comment: Not sure how to scroll inside a dropdown menu, but I'll figure it out eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Just tabbing out of the dropdown list should work in most cases. try this solution,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/manuel")

maerke = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_carSelectedMake"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-results-1"]/li[75]/div').click()


search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='s2id_autogen1_search']")
search.send_keys(Keys.TAB) #This should close the menu
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't :( Previously I found out, there's some sort of layer over, "select2-drop-mask" it's called. Keeping the script from getting out of field 1